# System.Diagnostics.Process takes more time compared to command prompt

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, vhd, waitforexit

I am trying to mount VHD file from inside c# code using System.Diagnostics.Process to execute diskpart.exe command.

Below is code snippet that i use:

```
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "diskpart.exe";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        process.Start();
        StreamWriter writer = process.StandardInput;

        writer.Write("select vdisk file=" + vhdfile + System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("attach vdisk" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("online disk" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("select part 1" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("remove all" + System.Environment.NewLine);
        writer.Write("assign mount=" + mountpoint + System.Environment.NewLine);

        writer.Close();

        process.WaitForExit();
        process.Close();
```

The problem is if i execute the same command in command prompt (using batch file), it takes around 0.5 second to execute. But if i run the above code, it takes around 5 seconds for WaitForExit() to return.

I tried setting RedirectStandardOutput and RedirectStandardError both true and false but i see no difference.

Please let me know what i might be doing wrong here.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't say for certain, but might it be that the batch script simply queues the commands to be ran, but exists after they're queued. Whereas the Process waits for every command to finish before exiting

Comment: I tried putting these commands into a batch script and called the batch script from Process(). It also takes around 5 seconds to return from WaitForExit().

Comment: Then might it be that it's when the batch script is ran through standard measures (double clicking, aka opening in CMD)? Not saying it is, but I can't see what else would be the answer